# Error in generated js by typescript compiler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a problem with type script generated js file and I can't solve it, this is my service file that I have problem with it:

```
namespace Providers {

    export interface IProvider {
        loadTranslations(translations: ITranslations, locale: string);
    }
    module.provider('lego', LegoProvider); 

    class LegoProvider implements ng.IServiceProvider ,IProvider{

        loadTranslations(translations:ITranslations , locale: string) {
            ......
        }

        $get() {
            .....
        }
    }

}
```

and generated js file is:

```
var Providers;
(function (Providers) {
    module.provider('lego', LegoProvider); // this is the problem
var LegoProvider = (function () {
    function LegoProvider() {
}
LegoProvider.prototype.loadTranslations = function (translations, locale) {
};
LegoProvider.prototype.$get = function () {
};
return LegoProvider;
}());
})(Providers || (Providers = {}));
```

It throws error because of the LegoProvider is variable and in that line it is still undefined. when I change code with this, it works correctly:

```
namespace Providers {

    export interface IProvider {
        loadTranslations(translations: ITranslations, locale: string);
    }


    class LegoProvider implements ng.IServiceProvider ,IProvider{

        loadTranslations(translations:ITranslations , locale: string) {
            ......
        }

        $get() {
            .....
        }
    }
    module.provider('lego', LegoProvider); // I've moved this line to bottom

}
```

In typescript code LegoProvider class is accessible from both positions and it doesn't make sense for me that the first position doesn't work

Comment: You're referring to `LegoProvider` before you've initialized it. Makes sense to me that that's a problem, which you've solved by waiting to use it until after you've initialized it. (FWIW, in ES2015, you can't access the constructor created via `class` before the `class` statement in the source; you get an error. TypeScript's apparently not being as strict about it, but fundamentally looks like the same problem.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The way you've fixed it in your question is the only way that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a classic hoisting issue:

The generated js file has a provider that is in fact a constructor function that is stored in a variable (an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to be percise):

```
var LegoProvider = (function () {
    function LegoProvider() { ...
```

When you register the provider to your app, the variable hasn't been initialized yet, only declared. This is what actually happens:

```
   var LegoProvider = undefined; // hoisting

   module.provider('lego', LegoProvider);

   LegoProvider = (function () {
       function LegoProvider() { ...
```

Your correction has moved the registration after the full initialization of your `LegoProvider` class.

Comment: Yes I know, And the problem is how to solve it without moving the registration line?